# Pyspark with Iceberg Catalog not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I'm attempting to create a basic Iceberg table and query it using PySpark on my local Mac. However, I'm encountering an issue where my code is unable to locate the catalog that I previously created with PySpark SQL.

The command I'm using to create the catalog is:

```
spark-sql --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.4.2 \
--conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local.type=hadoop \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse=~/warehouse
```

Afterwards I create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE local.db.table (id bigint, data string) USING iceberg;
```

```
Spark master: local[*], Application Id: local-1701166423847
spark-sql (default)> CREATE TABLE local.db.table (id bigint, data string) USING iceberg;
Time taken: 1.247 seconds
spark-sql (default)> use local;
Time taken: 0.02 seconds
spark-sql ()> select * from db.table;
Time taken: 0.997 seconds
```

When I try to connect to the catalog with pyspark I run into

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'local': org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.

```
import pyspark

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = (pyspark.SparkConf().
            setAppName("App").
            set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12:1.4.2').
            set('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions').
            set('spark.sql.catalog.local', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog').
            set('spark.sql.catalog.local.type', 'hadoop').
            set('spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse', '~/warehouse')
            )

    # session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    spark = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
             .master("local[2]")
             .config(conf=conf)
             .getOrCreate())

    spark.sql('use local')
```

Full Exception:

```
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'local': org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.catalogPluginClassNotFoundForCatalogError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$catalog$1(CatalogManager.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.catalog(CatalogManager.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog$CatalogAndNamespace$.unapply(LookupCatalog.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$4(AnalysisHelper.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.SetCatalogAndNamespace.mapChildren(v2Commands.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:222)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:60)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with spark 3.5 and iceberg 1.4.2

Comment: add: set('spark.sql.defaultCatalog', 'local') to your spark configuration and when calling 'use', call it with db: 'use db'. Basically, local is your catalog, db is your database.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2:

Use `use local.db` instead to switch to another db, not catalog.

UPDATE:

After hours of searching config problem which leads to spark cannot find iceberg catalog. Finally i found this is not a problem.

Spark's catalog are lazy initialized until been used. You can either query iceberg table first or use `spark.sql("use local.db")` make spark to init local catalog.

PS: `spark.catalog.listCatalogs()` only shows initialized catalogs.

---

I have same problem: fine with bin/spark-sql; but cannot find iceberg catalog with bin/pyspark:

```
> bin/pyspark \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local.type=hadoop \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse=/user/iceberg/warehouse
Python 3.11.3 (main, Jan 10 2024, 18:57:47) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.5.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.11.3 (main, Jan 10 2024 18:57:47)
Spark context Web UI available at http://127.0.0.1:4041
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1706523236880).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.catalog.listCatalogs()
[CatalogMetadata(name='spark_catalog', description=None)]
```